# Production Elixir/Phoenix app hogs CPU

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, cowboy

I have an Elixir/Phoenix running in production and after a while one of the beam.smp processes goes to 100% CPU load (sometimes more than one process). I'm not aware of any trigger causing this. How can I find out what's happening?

EDIT:

I ran iex on the server and connected to the Phoenix node. Than I ran etop and got this output:

```
Load:  cpu       100               Memory:  total       69429    binary      10568
        procs     303                        processes   16656    code        20194
        runq        1                        atom          727    ets          7205
Pid            Name or Initial Func    Time    Reds  Memory    MsgQ Current Function
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<19947.645.0>  cowboy_protocol:init     '-'90164000   88736       0 'Elixir.MyApp.Error
<19947.902.0>  cowboy_protocol:init     '-'88696000   88744       0 'Elixir.MyApp.Error
<19947.242.0>  'Elixir.Redix.Connec     '-'   11697   24704       0 gen_server:loop/6
<19947.240.0>  Elixir.Exq               '-'   10284   24664       0 gen_server:loop/6
<19947.236.0>  Elixir.Exq.Redis.Cli     '-'    9597   34520       0 gen_server:loop/6
<19947.1695.0> etop_txt:init/1          '-'    6258  230504       0 etop:update/1
<19947.245.0>  Elixir.Exq.Scheduler     '-'    4831   24664       0 gen_server:loop/6
<19947.241.0>  'Elixir.Redix.Connec     '-'    2339    8856       0 gen_server:loop/6
<19947.426.0>  Elixir.MyApp.Presen      '-'     262  143160       0 gen_server:loop/6
<19947.238.0>  Elixir.Exq.Stats         '-'     105   42344       0 gen_server:loop/6
========================================================================================
```

Those two `cowboy_protocol:init`entries causing the problem. But why ... and how can I stop/prevent/debug it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Processes started with `cowboy_protocol:init` are the processes that handle HTTP requests. The high reduction count would suggests they are stuck in some kind of infinite loop - both processes seem to be executing the same function - there's extremely high chance this function is faulty.

An infinite loop in tail position doesn't consume any additional memory - only CPU. This is very much a feature - and exactly how a GenServer works - an infinite loop in tail position, so the compiler (or runtime) have no way of distinguishing between faulty and correct code that uses this pattern.

This is also very much a tribute to the praised "fault tolerance" of Erlang/Elixir - even though there exists an infinite loop in one branch of the program, the rest functions completely normally, timely responding to requests. Very few platforms are able to do that.

Comment: I found the reason for this. I had a template which had an image tag with a url to an image that does not exist anymore and I forgot to updated the tag. But how can this cause such a thing?!

Comment: It looks like every request to a non-existing image causes this. This can not be normal ...

Comment: Have you looked at the function listed in the etop output as "Current function"? The start of the module name is prefixed with `MyApp`, so I assume it's your code. That's most probably the function where the error occurred.

Comment: I also updated the answer to reference the "This can not be normal" claim - it very much is.

Comment: In responds to your last change: I only recognised this behaviour because of my server monitoring reporting cpu usage of 100%. The program was fully responding and quick and alive as always. That's amazing. But nevertheless accessing a non-existent asset/route causing this is very strange isn't it?.

Comment: One last comment on this: I begin to suspect that AppSignal might not work correctly in some constellations. For now I have defined a catch-all route at the end that responds with a 404.

Comment: Have you investigated the function showed in the etop output? I can see everything, but the module name starts with `MyApp.Error` - that function is most probably the one with infinite loop.

Comment: MyApp.Error is not the full name (I replaced the actual app name with MyApp to make it more clear) and name got truncated by etop. The thing is that three modules start with MyApp.Error (ErrorView, ErrorController, ErrorHelpers) and I don't know which one causes the problem. Is there a way to get a wider output from etop?

Comment: I'm not sure, I never actually used etop. You can access the raw data about current function process executes with `Process.info(pid, :current_function)`. IEx has a `pid/3` helper to construct a pid when you know the numbers, so `Process.info(pid(19947,645,0), :current_function)` from IEx assuming output as in the initial post.

Comment: It just happen again and it's `MyApp.ErrorView.render/1`. I guess it fails and calls itself? I will try to look deeper into this. But `Process.info` really helped finding this little bugger.